# How to remove special characters and codes (using jQuery) from SharePoint rendered html?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am Working on a branding of share-point application. In some cases, rendered html contains codes like '​`&#8203;`'. In my slider, these are generated 8 times and in modal and content pages, their count is different. These codes are generating undesired white space. How can I remove these using jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the most annoying (and there are so many to choose from) things that SP does. We have a lot of lists that are used to display information. I found that preventing the zero width characters from getting into the list items in the first place was the best way to go about it.

There are probably other ways to attack this system wide, but I add the following code to all of our new/edit forms for lists that will be used to display content.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function PreSaveAction(){
  // remove all the zero width spaces &#8203; from the fields.

  jQuery('.ms-rtestate-field div[contenteditable=true]').each(function(index,element)  {
       var exp = new RegExp(String.fromCharCode(8203),"g");
       var editor= jQuery(element);
       var txt = editor.html()
           txt = txt.replace(exp,'');
           txt = txt.replace(/&nbsp;/g,' ')
           txt = txt.replace(/ {2,}/g,' ');
       editor.html(txt);
  });

  return true;
}
</script>
```

This also gets rid of the non-breaking spaces and if somebody tries to line something up with a bunch of spaces. You can remove the last two `txt.replace()` lines if you don't want that.

We've been using this more than a year without problems in our 2013 on-prem site.

Answer (score 1):

These are Unicode strings, the one you have there is space with 0 width (technically shouldn't add any width)... Microsoft's html generator adds these to control line breaks.

This will remove any non ascii characters. There may be unintended results from removing these without being more specific (so try in a test area, or better yet a development environment)

```
str.replace(/[^\x00-\x7F]/g, "");
```